# Debug script code that is being executed with Roslyn CSharpScript

Tags: roslyn

I created this test console application to run some C# code with the Roslyn scripting engine (in the *Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting* nuget package).

```cs
     string code = "int test = 123;\r\nConsole.WriteLine(\"hello, world!\");";
     var options = ScriptOptions.Default.WithImports("System");
     var script = CSharpScript.Create(code, options);
     await script.RunAsync();
```

This works, but now I would also like the option of somehow debugging into the script that is being executed. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Hello Wim. Thanks a lot for sharing your code. I want to do macros for an application. I'm  already using RoslynPad as the editor and it works fine. The problem is debugging the macro and you seems to have found the solution. Can I communicate with you (my email is ericouellet2@gmail.com if you agree just tell me) and what makes Visual Studio starts and breaks on your code? The ".Wait" ?

Comment: @EricOuellet 1) Note that you're commenting on the question, but the answer is below. 2) In the answer below, the Visual Studio debugger will show the CSharpScript code if you "Step Into" (F11) the RunAsync call. 3) The .Wait call is a bad example from me which could cause deadlocks, it would be better to make the calling method async and to use the await keyword. I'll edit to eliminate the .Wait.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Figured out a way to do it by writing the code to a temporary file, and adding debugging information pointing to that file. Then I can step into the RunAsync call, and visual studio will load the temporary file, show an execution pointer, and will let me inspect variables.

```cs
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace RoslynScriptingTest
{
   class Program
   {
      static async Task Main(string[] args)
      {
         string code = "int test = 123;\r\nConsole.WriteLine(\"hello, world!\");";
         string tmpFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
         var encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
         File.WriteAllText(tmpFile, code, encoding);
         try
         {
            var options = ScriptOptions.Default
               .WithImports("System")
               .WithEmitDebugInformation(true)
               .WithFilePath(tmpFile)
               .WithFileEncoding(encoding);
            var script = CSharpScript.Create(code, options);
            await script.RunAsync();   
         }
         finally
         {
            File.Delete(tmpFile);
         }
         Console.ReadKey();
      }
   }
}
```

The debugging only seems to work when "just my code" is enabled in the visual studio debugger settings.

In my actual use case, I'm actually loading the code from an XML file, so it would be better if I could point to that original file and map the line numbers somehow. But this is already a good start.

Comment: you can use GetDiagnostics method like this:

script.Compile();
var compilation = script.GetCompilation();
var diagnostic = compilation.GetDiagnostics();
Console.WriteLine($"Found errors: {diagnostic.Count()}");
foreach (var d in diagnostic)
            {
             Console.WriteLine($"{d.Location.GetLineSpan()} {d.Severity} {d.Id}: {d.GetMessage()}");
            }

Comment: @Krahu: the question was about debugging, not about getting the list of compiler errors

Comment: @WimCoenen, Thanks for your answer.I tested something similar with an old version of Roslyn. I added "Debugger.Break() into the script". It stopped into the script but stopped all the application (all threads). Do you know if there is way to only stop the script thread being debugged?

Comment: @EricOuellet Once you hit the breakpoint in the script, you can use the Debug->Windows->Threads window to choose which threads you want to freeze or thaw, and then resume execution to run any non-frozen threads. You cannot however step through one thread with the debugger while all the others continue to run. This is not specific to Roslyn it's just how debugging in any multi-threaded application works.